# Depuración de proyecto Java Web con STS y Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, spring-tool-suite

Estoy realizando un proyecto java web en STS basado en Gradle y, cada vez que lo quiero ejecutar debo construir el war y subirlo a un servidor local (Tomcat por ejemplo). En netbeans con maven es muy sencilla esta tarea ya que el propio IDE es el que levanta una instancia de Tomcat y es posible realizar una depuración (breakpoints, etc) relativamente sencilla. Alguien sabe como hacer lo mismo usando Gradle y STS??

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo que yo hago es preparar un tomcat/jetty embebido en la aplicación en una clase de test, de modo que ejecuto el test en modo debug y luego tengo la aplicación corriendo en local en modo debug para que la explote como quisiera.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes desplegar tu aplicacion en jetty con gradle en modo depuración:

```
 $ export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=n"

 $ gradle jettyRun
```

y luego utilizar el depurador(debug) remoto de sts utilizando el puerto que configures, en este caso el 9999.

Answer (score 0):

Existen plugin para Gradle para desplegar aplicaciones en Tomcat y Jetty. Una vez lo instales con ejecutar gradle en modo depuración sería suficiente para poder realizar lo que indicas.

Con Maven sería similar.

Otra opción sería probar a configurar un servidor tomcat en la vista de servidores. STS detecta los proyectos web y te permite agregarlo al servidor configurado. Cualquier cambio en el proyecto o dependencias lo detectará y cuando arranques el servidor desde dicha vista desplegará automáticamente la aplicación.
Con ambas opciones te ahorrarías bastante tiempo.